# Why does the value of a pointer of a pointer have undefined behaviour?

Tags: c, pointers, undefined-behavior

Here is my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

char ** func()
{
    char list[2][20] = {"a140","3.14"};
    char * l[2] = {list[0], list[1]};
    char ** point = l;
    return point;
}

int main()
{
    char ** pointers;
    pointers = func();
    printf("%d", *pointers[0]);
}
```

Here i am trying to calling a function that returns a pointer to an array of pointers that point to a value of an array that contains characters.

But something went wrong and when i run this code it outputs:

```
97
```

Comment: It's because you are returning a pointer to a local variable.  Local variables become invalid when the function exits and using it after that is UB.

Comment: So what is the correct way to do something like this?

Comment: One way would be to declare `list` by `static char list[2][20] = ...`.  That way, the array stays in memory even after the function returns.

Comment: One way is to dynamically allocate the memory that needs to outlive the function.  But then you need to remember to deallocate it when you are finished.

Comment: What were you expecting instead of `97`?

Comment: You actually got the "correct" result because 97 is the ASCII code of `a` which is `l[0][0]`. But you can't rely on that happening since you have undefined behavior.

Comment: @DanielWalker I changed it to ```static char list[2][20]``` and it behaves in the same way.

Comment: @Cheatah An error telling me that ```a140 is not an interger```

Comment: As @interjay said, 97 is actually the correct answer.  You're printing `'a'` (the first character in `"a140"`) as an integer (`%d`).  In ASCII, `'a'` is 97.

Comment: @DanielWalker why does it not try to print the whole string?

Comment: because `*pointers` is a `char *` and `**pointers` is a char.

Comment: If you want to print the string, use `printf("%s\n", *pointers)` or `puts(pointers[0])`

Comment: then how do i access the second adress

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value being returned is a pointer to a local variable, specifically `&l[0]`.  After the function returns, the lifetime of this variable ends.  So when you attempt to dereference the returned pointer, you're attempting to access an object after its lifetime has ended.  This triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Your function needs to dynamically allocate memory for the array of strings to be returned.

```
const char **func()
{
    const char **l = malloc(2 * sizeof *l);
    l[0] = "a140";
    l[1] = "3.14";
    return l;
}
```

Note also that the output will remain the same, since what you're printing is the ASCII value of the first character of the first string.  If you want to print the entire string, don't dereference `pointers[0]` and use the `%s` format specifier:

```
printf("%s", pointers[0]);
```

Comment: Could you please explain how this code works, mainly malloc and why you are returning 1.

Comment: @EvandroFilipe The `malloc` function allocates memory dynamically, and this memory remains valid for the lifetime of the program (or until it is passed to `free`).  And what's being returned is the value of the variable `l`, not the number 1.

Comment: how do i pass this memory to free or do i not have to?

Comment: @EvandroFilipe After you're done using the memory, call `free(pointers)`.

Comment: Thank you for being really patient with me and giving me the answers. Sorry if i was an annoyance.

Answer (score 4):

you can also

```
char ** func(void)
{
    static char *list[] = {"a140","3.14"};
    return list;
}
```

or

```
/* LOL everything is list */
typedef struct
{
    char *list[2];
}list;

list func(void)
{
    list list = {{"a140","3.14"}};
    return list;
}

int main(void)
{
    char **list = (func()).list;

    printf("%s %s\n", list[0], list[1]);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/hhjK8G7TP